# How to get data starting with particular alphabet in loopback.js

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I want to create autocomplete in loopback.js . So, if user type "a", it should go to database and shows all the emails starting with a . For this, I have "allusers" model. With simple get request, it shows me result like this

```
[
  {
    "users": "ank1@gmail.com",
    "id": "5a439dea4da34b14040cb1b2"
  },
  {
    "users": "ank2@gmail.com",
    "id": "5a439df14da34b14040cb1b3"
  },
  {
    "users": "ank3@gmail.com",
    "id": "5a439df84da34b14040cb1b4"
  },
  {
    "users": "ank4@gmail.com",
    "id": "5a439e004da34b14040cb1b5"
  },
  {
    "users": "ank5@gmail.com",
    "id": "5a439e044da34b14040cb1b6"
  },
  {
    "users": "ank6@gmail.com",
    "id": "5a439e084da34b14040cb1b7"
  }
]
```

So,how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This is what works for me.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/allusers?filter[where][users][like]=a&filter[limit]=6
```

Than, I can just make more api calls as user input more text into the input box. This works perfectly for me.